# Find item in set via hash

Tags: python, hash, set

Is there a fast way to find an object of a set, if I know how the hash was calculated?

I have the following class, `uid` is an unique string (never used twice for different objects):

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, uid):
        self.uid = uid
        self.__hash = hash(self.uid)

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.__hash

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__hash == other.__hash
```

I have a set created with different `uid`s:

```
foos = {Foo('a'), Foo('b'), Foo('c')}
```

I now wonder, if I want to have the item, which was initialized with `b`, if there is a faster (and if possible more pythonic) way to get the element out of the sets than

```
b_object = next(foo for foo in foos if foo.uid == 'b')
```

since I could get `hash_b = hash('b')`, which should provide somehow faster access, if the set is really huge (which is in my particular case obviously the case).

Comment: You should probably think about a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, I finally used the answer of Reut Sharabani. Anyway, I still wonder, if there exists a pythonmethod, which allows to fast access to items of a set, if I know their hash value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're using this for, but you could do something like:

```
uid_to_foo = {foo.uid: foo for foo in foos}

# use 'uid_to_foo[some_foo.uid]' to find an instance fast
```

And now you get fast access to any `Foo` instance through it's `uid`.

Note that your current hash does not **promise** no collisions (although they are probably not likely).

You can even have this in the class itself:

```
class Foo():

    # add class dictionary mapping uids to foos
    uid_to_foo = {}

    def __init__(self, uid):
        self.uid = uid
        self.__hash = hash(self.uid)

        # add to class-level mapping
        Foo.uid_to_foo[uid] = self

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.__hash

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__hash == other.__hash
```

To create a mapping for every sub-class you can do something like (as asked in comments), using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
class Base():

    # add class dictionary mapping uids to instances
    uid_to_obj = defaultdict(dict)

    def __init__(self, uid):
        self.uid = uid
        self.__hash = hash(self.uid)

        # add specific sub-class mapping for each sub-class
        Foo.uid_to_obj[type(self).__name__][uid] = self

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.__hash

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__hash == other.__hash
```

The class-specific dictionaries are now obviously under `Foo.uid_to_obj[type(self).__name__]`.

Comment: Yes, a dictionary is the usual approach, but I need to perform several union, intersect and so on methods, that’s why I made the decision for a set in the first place. But I like the idea of a class-level-dictionary to have the direct access to the objects.

Comment: This can be an addition, doesn't have to be a replacement :)

Comment: Is there any way to obtain this via inheritance without implement it in every child? Assuming I have a class `Bar(Foo)` and a class `Baz(Foo)`, I’d like to have for each class such a dictionary, but without defining it in each child-class and assigning `self` to the key `uid` to reduce duplicated code. So the individual dictionaries should be filled by calling `super().__init__(uid)`. But I assume, it is not possible to create the required dictonaries in `Foo.__init__(self, uid)` for the children...

Comment: @SebastianWerk A simple way that comes to mind is creating double-layer dictionary in the base class: class-name->uid->self. See edit.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I am not sure, if the code is more readable with `Foo.uid_to_obj['Bar'][uid]` than having code duplication and being able to use `Bar.uid_to_obj[uid]`, but thanks a lot for your examples, they helped a lot!

Comment: @SebastianWerk sure, no problem, you can discuss more options in Python's chat room if you are not sure what you need. Good luck.